# Change font-size of all text including buttons using LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change font-size of all text on my web including buttons, after clicling on button using LocalStorage.
It only change font-size of elements in tags like `<small>`, `<strong>` etc. (HTML Formatting text Tags)
but not in headers tag like `<h1>` or `<button>`.

My code:

```
mybutton.onclick = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("fontsize", "300%");
  location = location.href;
};

window.onload = function () {
  var fonts = localStorage.getItem("fontsize");
  body.style.fontSize = fonts;
```

Comment: `body.style.fontSize` will give font-size to only body tag. It will not override font-sizes of other stages which are specified by their own css.

Comment: @DhruviMakvana Body fontsize inherits to all childrens. But 300% should be 3em which will then be 3em of the standard 16px = 48px; otherwise the font size has to be set to a fixed px value.

Comment: When i change 300% to px it doesnt work either.  Is it possible to overide font-sizes with their own css? Or is it another way to change font-size on the whole website after clicking on button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using font size in local Storage, store the class name and add class through javascript.

For css, you can do this: `*` selector selects all the elements.
I tried this locally and it worked, also `!important` is necessary for it to override any other styles.

```
.fontSize * {
    font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that after refreshing the page, the css resets.

Comment: Is it possible to save css to not reset after changing tabs?

Comment: place that css inside your css file and then you can fetch the class from localstorage and use it. it should work even with refresh.

Comment: How to fetch class from localStorage? Can you explain?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, explain more that what you want to achieve.